# how to prevent access to the static files in flask

Tags: python, flask

I have created the backend using Flask and stored multiple images in the images folder which is further inside the static folder. Below is the screenshot for a better understanding.

[Screenshot of the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaGLT.png)
when I try to access this folder using the URL I can access all the images by searching in the search tab. I have also pasted a screenshot for that.

[Screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEw56.png)

```
@app.route('/static/images/<path:filename>')
def serve_static(filename):
   return render_template('404.html')
```

I was able to prevent the access but now any images on the web app are not getting rendered. Below is a  screenshot for that as well.

[The image is not rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uf9gZ.png)

and without the above code, the web page looks like below:

[Without the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUAe7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Typically in these web framework systems, the static folder is open for viewing as you have experienced. One workaround is to create a different folder at the same level as the static folder (in the same folder where the static folder resides) and you can set up the security/permissions for this other/new folder as needed for your project without disrupting the default security/permissions setup of the static folder. You would place your image files in this other/new folder. You may need to rework the routing logic for your project as needed.

Comment: does this problem also comes with Django

Comment: I am not sure about Django. My direct experience is with Pyramid which has this same issue. In one of my projects, I was able to successfully implement the approach I have suggested in this answer to have better security on some groups of files where specific data files (json files in my case) were intended only for specific users.

Answer (score 0):

When an image is loaded on a webpage, it is given a `Referer` header of the current webpage. This is useful to prevent access from other sources to the images.

To only allow static images access to your website:

```py
from flask import request

@app.route('/static/images/<path:filename>')
def serve_static(filename):
   referrer = request.referrer
   if referrer != 'http://127.0.0.1/':
      return render_template('404.html')
   return send_from_directory('images', filename)
```

Note: if you have the `referrerPolicy="no-referrer"` attribute in your `<img>` tag, it will not provide a `Referer` header when requesting the image.

This is only a *soft* way of preventing the problem. As with most things, you cannot fully protect your images. It's possible to use cURL and provide the same `Referer` header.